# How To Use toLowerCase in Selector Condition In jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

```
var path = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var element = jq_menu("#topMenu a[href='" + path + "']");
element.parent().closest('li').addClass('active');
```

I use this codes for select active menu.

I want convert `href` value to `lowerCase` at line 2.

How can I do that?

Comment: `path` is a string so... `path.toLowerCase()` O.o

Comment: have you tried `path.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: This doesn't seen to be appropriate question. If people keep asking such questions it will be trillions and trillions of questions here. Haven't you used `toLowerCase()` function?

Comment: i know how to convert path toLowerCase I need convert href Value to LowerCase

Comment: Use `$("#topMenu a").attr("href", function(i, attr){return attr.toLowerCase();});` See https://jsfiddle.net/v0jck2v4/

Comment: A simple googling for [javascript lowercase string](https://www.google.hu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20lower%20case%20string) will give you the answer in the f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ second result.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the href value to lowercase simply like I've done below, it's just a JavaScript object value handling. You can run it:

```js
// All is happening on load, just for example
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Before
  console.log($('a#my-selector').attr('href'));
  // Getting value and converting
  var value = $('a#my-selector').attr('href').toLowerCase();

  // ..you can use it where you want now..

  // I'm just setting it back to the element..
  $('a#my-selector').attr('href', value);
  // After
  console.log($('a#my-selector').attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="my-selector" href="LINK-UPPER-CASE">I'm uppercase</a>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

Since path is a string, instead, use;

```
var path = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var element = jq_menu("#topMenu a[href='" + path.toLowerCase() + "']");
element.parent().closest('li').addClass('active');
```

Comment: i want convert href value to LowerCase

Comment: Please read comments on other answer. Also, this has been addressed in comments under question, so unless you add something extra, there is no need for it.

Comment: i want compare LowerCased `href  ` And LowerCased `path` and return the element